# Returning Dictionary <string,List<string> with Linq from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

i'm new in `LINQ` i want to group data from a `DataTable` with a specific column `field1` value

Like this `Dictionary<string,List <row>>`

I tried this code

```
  var results = from e in data.AsEnumerable()
                group e by e.Field<string>("field1") into g
                select new {  e.Field<string>("field1"), g.ToList() } ;
```

I don't want to do this operation with `foreach` statement

Im doing it like this and i want it with `LINQ`

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    string field1Val = row.Filed<string>("field1");

    if (!sotrtedResult.ContainsKey(field1Val ))
    {
        sotrtedResult.Add(field1Val , new List<DataRow>() { row });
    }
    else
    {
        sotrtedResult[field1Val].Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following snippet:

```
var results = (from e in data.AsEnumerable()
              group e by e.Field<string>("field1") into g
              select new 
              {  
                  field1 = g.Key, 
                  values = g.Select(r=>r).ToList() 
              }).ToDictionary(x=>x.field1, x=>x.values);
```

When you group by a field, you could access it, when you make the projection as `g.Key`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip . i want to store a `DataRow` not a spesific field . I updated my post check how i'm doing it with `foreach`

Comment: You are welcome. Please check by update. Please not that your dictionary now will not be a `Dictionary<string, List<string>` as your title mentions but it would be a `Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>`.

Comment: Thanks it's work fine . I must take some courses on Linq I think its a powerful tool :) and you are right I made a mistake with the title

Comment: You are welcome ! LINQ is awesome. Not a problem at all :)